# Setting -Duser.timezone Property for Changing JRE timezone

Tags: java, jvm, timezone, java-7, jvm-arguments

I want to change the JRE timezone for my server based on Windows and I tested it by running a simple program of just printing a date in this way

```
C:\Users\nikhila\workspace\TimezoneTest\src>java -Duser.timezone="America/New_York" TimezoneTest
```

Output:

```
Date = Thu Mar 03 05:13:21 EST 2016
```

This was the program

```
import java.util.Date;

public class TimezoneTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Date = " + new Date());

    }
}
```

So I was running this program in IST timezone and you can see that the timezone is changed successfully.

So we have multiple application running on our server and we want to change it at one. So just want to check can we set this `-Duser.timezone` property using environment variables or some other way at one place.

Comment: Better idea: stop your code from depending on the system default time zone. It's almost *always* a bad idea, particularly for server-side apps.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if there is anything you missed because it appears to work for you?

Comment: @PeterLawrey it is running when I am running a test program by using duser.timezone argument but how to set it permanently in the system?
Is it possible through environment variables

Comment: If your server is running in windows, change the timezone in windows and will affect all running java VMs. see : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/time-zone002.html

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah but it is a legacy code and the project is in maintenance mode. We don't want to disturb any existing code and creating other troubles for our clients. So is there any other way!!!

Comment: How you set it in your operating system, depends on your OS. On Linux you can set `export TZ=` though as JonSkeet mentions you shouldn't use the default timezone for anything important in the first place.

Comment: @pringi Is is not happening when we change the system timezone it takes its  default value as GMT.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal do you mean GMT+5 ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah and we are using windows operating system...

Comment: If you have one JVM instance per customer, the -D solution is fine. But be aware that the modification is for the whole JVM.

Comment: @Xvolks we are fine with it but how to change it for the JVM in a common way

Comment: @nikhil-agrawal it depends of the server and how you launch it. I have experience with Tomcat under Linux, so not relevant for your case. Usually our service are launched with TanukiSoftware wrapper...

Comment: @Xvolks we have all the application running on tomcat only So If you can suggest us what you have done just its an OS difference then too I can get some clue!!!!

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal the -D option may go to CATALINA_OPTS or JAVA_OPTS environnement variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105241/discussion-between-nikhil-agrawal-and-xvolks).